# Hide some groups from Access Rights page in res.users

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I need to hide default `Access Rights` groups in res.users page. I have tried to hide these groups by create a new group and assign to it but didn't work.

**I tried**

```
      <record id="account.group_account_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, False, [ref('mymodule.group_invisible')])]"/>
      </record>
```

How can i hide it?